# My purge command keeps getting rate limited

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my purge command and although it works fine it keeps getting rate limited after I purge 30 massages or more.

```
@commands.command()
async def purge(self, ctx, num):
   '''
   Clears messages.
   '''
   embed = discord.Embed(title="**MESSAGES PURGED**", description=" ", color=0x0059ff)
   async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=int(num) + 1):
   await message.delete(delay=0.5)
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does the ratelimit says? It tells you more why you are being ratelimited.

Comment: Let's correct the way of your code. You can use `purge` coroutine in discord.py library.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your code and I understood that you are using a difficult path to create a `purge` command. `Discord.py` library has a coroutine called `purge` whose job is just to delete messages. Rather than using a loop and various other methods, it would be better to use it.

---

#### I created a `purge` command first which has the following code:

```
@nucleobot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, limit: int):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    purge_embed = discord.Embed(title='Purge [!purge]', description=f'Successfully purged {limit} messages. \n Command executed by {ctx.author}.', color=discord.Colour.random())
    purge_embed.set_footer(text=str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=purge_embed, delete_after=True)
```

#### How does this code work?

1. The command usage is deleted, i.e., `!purge 10` would be deleted when sent into the chat.
2. It would pause for 1 second due to `await asyncio.sleep(1)`. You would need to import asyncio in order to use it. (You might know that already :D)
3. The number of messages your entered are cleared from the channel using `await ctx.message.delete(limit=limit)` (This is a discord.py coroutine)
4. `purge_embed` is the embed variable which is used to send the embed after the deletion. I have used `datetime` module to add the time of the command completion on the embed. (You need to import datetime as well, but only if you want to use it. If not then remove the footer code.)

This would make up your complete and working `purge` command. :D

---

#### Examples with images.

I created a new channel and added 10 messages with numbers from 1 to 10 as shown below:

[image: Messages in Trail]

Then I entered the command in the message box and it was like (I know it was not needed but never mind):

[image: Command Entered]

After I sent this message and the command was executed, the purge successful embed was posted by the bot:

[image: Successful Purge]

---

I was glad I could help. Any doubts of confusions are appreciated. Ask me anytime. :D

Thank You! :)

Comment: Thank you I understood my mistake.

Comment: Anytime! :D I am glad to help! :)

Comment: hey I'm still getting rate limited

Comment: What do you literally mean by `rate limiting`?

Comment: `WARNING:discord.http:We are being rate limited. Retrying in 3.70 seconds. Handled under the bucket "724975725488373823:None:/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231249/discussion-between-bhavyadeep-yadav-and-nikos).